# tidy_parse_string change the locale previously set with setlocale

Tags: php, locale, tidy

The function `tidy_parse_string` change my locale to 'C'.

```php
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');

/* [...] */

echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0); // Show "de_DE"
$tidy = tidy_parse_string($text, $config, 'UTF8');
echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0); // show "C" instead of "de_DE"
?>
```

There is an option to prevent it?

There is nothing about it in the [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.parsestring.php) and [Tidy](http://api.html-tidy.org/tidy/quickref_5.6.0.html) documentation.

---

I know I can simply re-change my locale after tidy function with

```php
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');

/* [...] */

$oldLocale = setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
$tidy = tidy_parse_string($text, $config, 'UTF8');
setlocale(LC_ALL, $oldLocale);
?>
```

but I want to know if this is a feature, a bug or something else.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug: https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/issues/770.

So the workaround is to insert the setlocale after the call.

```php
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');

/* [...] */

$oldLocale = setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
$tidy = tidy_parse_string($text, $config, 'UTF8');
setlocale(LC_ALL, $oldLocale);
?>
```